# Use a button to display one array string at a time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, button

I'm creating a text generator that cycles through array strings one at a time in order from top to bottom, changing to the next string each time a button is pushed. The function below cycles through the strings in order, but it does all of them on repeat after a single push of the button. How can I tell the function to wait to display the next string until the button is pushed again?

```js
function newThing() {
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('thingDisplay').innerHTML = oddthing[i++];
    if (i == oddthing.length) i = 0;
    }, newThing.active);
}

var oddthing = [
'<p>111111111</p>',
'<p>222222222</p>',
'<p>333333333</p>',
'<p>444444444</p>',
'<p>555555555</p>',
'<p>666666666</p>',
'<p>777777777</p>',
'<p>888888888</p>',
'<p>999999999</p>'
]
```

```html
<div>
  <div align="center" id='thingDisplay'></div>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="box" id="button01" onclick="newThing()">New Thing</button>
</div>

<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
var oddthing = [
'<p>111111111</p>',
'<p>222222222</p>',
'<p>333333333</p>',
'<p>444444444</p>',
'<p>555555555</p>',
'<p>666666666</p>',
'<p>777777777</p>',
'<p>888888888</p>',
'<p>999999999</p>'
]

// add a global counter
var count = 0;

function newThing() {
    document.getElementById('thingDisplay').innerHTML = oddthing[count];
    count++;
    if (count >= oddthing.length) count = 0;
}
```

Comment: Requires 2 clicks to show first item when it gets to the last one. Try it yourself. Can put it in a stack snippet to run it here in the page by clicking on `<>` in answer editor

Comment: I've noticed that as well. This seems like the frontrunner solution right now, so what could be done to prevent the need to double click with each recycle?

Comment: Insert the html after the `if()` instead so it modifies the content for all cases

Comment: @guyw I've updated my answer to address that issue =)

Comment: you are a heroes! Thank you. I've been pulling my hair out for two weeks trying to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `setInterval`, and declare `i` outside of the function:

```js
function initDisplay($btn, $display, array) {
  var i = 0;
  $btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    $display.innerHTML = array[i++];
    if (i >= array.length) i = 0;
  });
}

initDisplay(
  document.getElementById('button01'),
  document.getElementById('thingDisplay'), [
    '<p>111111111</p>',
    '<p>222222222</p>',
    '<p>333333333</p>',
    '<p>444444444</p>',
    '<p>555555555</p>',
    '<p>666666666</p>',
    '<p>777777777</p>',
    '<p>888888888</p>',
    '<p>999999999</p>'
  ]
);

initDisplay(
  document.getElementById('button02'),
  document.getElementById('thingDisplay2'), [
    '<p>AAAAA</p>',
    '<p>BBBBB</p>',
    '<p>CCCCC</p>'
  ]
);
```

```html
<div>
  <div align="center" id='thingDisplay'>&nbsp;</div>
  <button class="box" id="button01">New Thing</button>
</div>

<div>
  <div align="center" id='thingDisplay2'>&nbsp;</div>
  <button class="box" id="button02">New Thing 2</button>
</div>

<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great when using a single array! The webpage I'm building includes multiple arrays, radio boxes and categories that users can choose from. Each radio box determines which array to pull the string from. This solution tends to display only the second and fourth strings when placed within a couple of if statements for some reason.

Comment: @guyw I updated my answer for it to work with multiple "displays". Don't know if that's what you're trying to achieve. Otherwise, maybe edit your question to give us more context

Comment: The page uses a single display and button for multiple arrays. For example, the array "oddthing" contained strings ranging from '1111111' to '999999'. There is a radio box titled 'oddthing' that the user needs to select in order for the button to pull a string from 'oddthing.' The page has multiple radio boxes that go to their respective arrays. Hope that makes sense. I apologize for my lack of detail; I'm new to the site and am learning as I go.